# Is there always acceleration due to gravity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, acceleration

Say I am standing motionless relative to Earth.  My weight is my mass multiplied by my acceleration.  My acceleration should be -9.8 m/s/s in this equation, but how am I accelerating without a change in velocity?

Answer (score 4):

> My weight is my mass multiplied by my acceleration.

Your weight is not your mass multiplied by your acceleration. Your weight is your mass multiplied by g which is the local free fall gravitational acceleration. It is only your acceleration if you are in free fall.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not always an acceleration due to gravity. There is always a *force*. The *net* force of all the forces $F_{\text{net}}$ on you is related to your acceleration $a$ and mass $m$ by $F_{\text{net}}=ma$. In this case, there is also the force of the ground upon you in the opposite direction resulting in zero net force.

Answer (score 0):

Newton's third law states that for every action force, there will be a reaction force in the opposite direction.  You exert a force on the ground, which is your weight.  However, according to Newton's third law, the reaction force of the ground pushes up on you too, so the net force acting on your body is $0$.  Hence, you will remain stationary.

Comment: You're putting the argunent upside down. If you are
standing on ground surely (by second law) resultant of (downward)
weight and (upward) ground push is zero. Then (third law) you may say
that your feet push (downward) on ground with a force equal to your
weight.